# Vector of three arrays of size 21 each with respect to an array of size 21

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, vector, minimization

I have vector = [array1, array2, array3] where each of these arrays are of size 21. I want to see how this vector is changing with respect to array4 which is also of size 21.
I want to see how each element of array 1, 2 ,3 is changing accordingly with respect to each element of array4. Can someone help me to write the code please.

Comment: `array4` is size 21 or size 3? Are `vector` and `array4` equals at beginning? please provide what you have tried and also an example of what you want to achieve

Comment: yes vector of size 3 but each array of size 21. i.e, array1=[element1, element2, .., element 21], array2=[element1, element2, .., element 21] , array3=[element1, element2, .., element 21]. And, I have an array4= [element1, element2, .., element 21]. I want to see how each element of arrays 1,2,3 is changing with respect to each element of array4. Thus, I created a vector called X where X=[array1,array2,array3]. Now I want to see X with respect to array4. (I want to iterate over each element of X and draw the change with respect to array 4)

Comment: provide your code, specifying what doesnt work properly

Comment: Why? You should share it in your question. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: vector = np.array([global_x1 , global_x2, global_x3])
colours = ['r', 'g', 'b']
plt.figure() # In this example, all the plots will be in one figure.
for i in range(len(vector)):
   plt.plot(slope_2nd_decay_int, vector[i], colours[i])
plt.show()

Comment: The code you have to share should be executable, so that others can run it and try to reproduce errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.